# Using time to get CPU usage of a process, but not its children

Tags: linux, bash, unix, performance, time

When using `time some_executable` - the system and user CPU time returned actually includes all the CPU time of any child processes launched by the named executable (this was news to me, actually).

I would like to get *just* the CPU time incurred by the launched process, however, and not its children.  Is that possible?

Comment: from `man time`: `Note: some shells (e.g., bash(1)) have a  built-in  time  command  that provides less functionality than the command described here.  To access the real command, you may need to specify its pathname (something like /usr/bin/time).`
I had to install time, but its output is way more verbose (than the built in time), maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are benchmarking a piece of software, you can get VERY fine-grained results with something like callgrind (`valgrind --tool=callgrind`).

If you're looking for something a tad weaker, `/proc/$PID/schedstat` contains useful numbers (such as "time this thread has used").